# How to force download files from a google storage bucket instead of opening it it browser?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have some audio files in a Google Bucket, and I am serving links to those file in a WordPress website.

How do I force download those files instead of playing in the browser.

Adding `&response-content-disposition=attachment;` to the end of the url doesn't work.

Tried in gsutil `gsutil setmeta -h 'Content-Disposition:attachment' gs://samplebucket/*/*.mp3`
I get the error

> CommandException: Invalid or disallowed header (u'content-disposition).
>
> Only these fields (plus x-goog-meta-* fields) can be set or unset:
> [u'cache-control', u'content-disposition', u'content-encoding', u'content-language', u'content-type']`

Comment: AFAICT your `gsutil` command should work.  However, the error you are getting has a leading `u'` on the "disallowed header", which implies to me something deeper is going on in how you are invoking gsutil.

Comment: C:\Users\BRVNBLD\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK> This is where am invoking the gsutil command.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same error if you invoke it in [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/)?

Comment: Ok, Got it worked out buddy, It was not working because I was running the command in the google cloud console on windows.weird.

Comment: Glad it is working for you, I suspect something was happening with how python was interacting with the windows shell escaping, but I don't know enough about the windows shell to provide a real answer as to what :)

Comment: hm, thanks mate, how does gsutil -m differ from gsutil -h?. I got a message suggesting me to use the latter.

Comment: use `gsutil help setmeta` and find out: "If you have a large number of objects to update you might want to use the gsutil -m option, to perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) update:"  You still have to use `-h` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by robsiemb, I had to invoke these commands under google cloud shell . In my case Windows shell turned out to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing object metadata, defining `attachment` into the `Content-Disposition` field